# Parse through a list of Ansible variables and refer to itself while running task

Tags: linux, ansible, tmux

## Problem

I have a simple Ansible playbook that creates a list of `tmux` sessions and then runs a script inside of each session. I am trying to give the `tmux` sessions names in my `vars.yml` file.

My problem is that I want to run the same command in all of the `tmux` sessions I create. Here is the simple playbook I have.

## Playbook

Obviously the playbook is broken in its current form. I having a hard time of figuring out how to:

1. Navigate to the correct directory for each unique `tmux` session (to a directory with the same name as the session)
2. Start a script (same name shared in all sessions) in the folder navigated to

.

```
---
- hosts: all

  vars_file:
    - vars.yml

  tasks:
    - name: "Create tmux sessions for each server."
      command: tmux new -d -s {{ servers }}

    - name: "Start each server in its tmux session."
      shell: >
        tmux send-keys -t {{ servers }} "./start.sh" Enter
```

## Variables

```
---
# Name of all tmux sessions running on server
servers:
  - creative
  - development
  - lobby
  - proxy
  - survival
  - workflow
```

Any tips for how I might be able to intelligently refer to the current variable executing within the shell command (e.g. `cd ~/{{ current_variable }}/scripts/ && ./start.sh`)? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the `servers` variable in your playbook:

In ansible 1.x this would be done:

```
---
- hosts: all

  vars_file:
    - vars.yml

  tasks:
    - name: "Create tmux sessions for each server."
      command: tmux new -d -s {{ item }}
      with_items: servers

    - name: "Start each server in its tmux session."
      shell: >
        tmux send-keys -t {{ item }} "./start.sh" Enter
      with_items: servers
```

In ansible 2.x you need to quote the variable used by the `with_items` directive: `"{{ servers }}"`.